# Visibility not changing on hover

Tags: css, hover

I'm working on a simple nav bar with a drop-down menu on hover using the visibility property. But when I hover, the condition does not take effect. What is the logic behind this?

http://jsfiddle.net/MAvQp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make the subitems visible with

```
ul li:hover ul{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

but the subitems `ul` is not nested inside an `li`, so `ul li ul` does not match the subitems. Therefore, change your html to something like

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1 
            <ul>
            <li>Sub-Menu1 Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub-Menu1 Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub-Menu1 Item 3</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
…

</ul>
```

please also see [my forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVVZz/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I appreciate it very greatly.

Answer (score 3):

Your html was malformed, the `ul` should be children of the `li` not siblings

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAvQp/4/)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now that you mention it. I wondering why they were block elements.